# How do I print items using a loop in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am very new to Shopify and I am trying to print items form my array. I have entered my text into a text field with the Shopify CMS. However, when I load the page in the browser, all I see is an empty `<ul>`. Therefore, there is something wrong with my loop below but I can't figure it. Any help welcome.

```
<div class="featured_item">
      <ul class="featured_item_list">
          {% for i in featured_items %}
          <li>
            <p>{{ i }}</p>
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
      </ul>
</div>


{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Featured items",
    "class": "section section_homepage section_featured_items",
    "settings": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "itemOne",
            "label": "Item one text"
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "itemTwo",
            "label": "Item two text"
        }
      ],
    "presets": [
        {
            "name": "Featured items",
            "category": "text"
        }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

Comment: I don't know Shopify but I do use Liquid from time to time. The loop itself looks fine to me. What happens if you write `{{ featured_items }}` outside the loop? Does that output anything?

Comment: If I add {{ featured_items }} inside a <h2> tag nothing gets printed.

Comment: So then your loop is not to blame; it's the `featured_items` variable that's missing or empty. I don't know how that should get filled, but you should look into that.

Comment: It should be {{ section.settings.itemOne }} and {{ section.settings.itemTwo }}

Answer (score 2):

You will need to read more about sections and how to use them properly: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections

At the moment you are trying to loop ... nothing.

There is no `featured_items` variable assign anywhere and even if it there was, there are no blocks ( the array that can be looped ).

When you are in a section and you want to get a specific field from the schema on that section you always go through the `section`.

So at the moment you have the following:

```
"settings": [
    {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "itemOne",
        "label": "Item one text"
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "itemTwo",
        "label": "Item two text"
    }
],
```

So you must call `section` beforehand and if you like to get the `itemOne` field you call it like so `section.settings.itemOne` since `itemOne` is present in the settings section.

The same applies for the second `itemTwo` which should be called as `section.settings.itemTwo`.

```
<div class="featured_item">
      <ul class="featured_item_list">
        <li>
            <p>{{ section.settings.itemOne }}</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>{{ section.settings.itemTwo }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

---

But since you are making a repeatable content is actually better to use BLOCKS instead.

The schema syntax for blocks is:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Featured items",
    "class": "section section_homepage section_featured_items",
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "some_type",
        "name": "Some Type",
        "settings": [
          {
            "id": "content",
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Content"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "presets": [
        {
          "name": "Featured items",
          "category": "text"
        }
   ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

And then since blocks are actually a repeatable content that returns an array, you call the `section.blocks` for the loop and it becomes like so:

```
<div class="featured_item">
    <ul class="featured_item_list">
        {% for block in section.blocks %}
            <li>
            <p>{{ block.settings.content }}</p>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

And you have now repeatable blocks that you can add multiply times in order to create a dynamic list instead of a fixed number.

Consider reading more about Sections and how to use them, since there are a lot more to them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand as your explanation was super clear and it communicated effectively the difference between using sections and blocks. Thank you very much for your help.